# how to check RSelenium navigate function returned proper page

Tags: rselenium

I've found some inconstistency in the `RSelenium` navigation function. Namely, I've started just the server this way:

```
rS <- rsDriver(browser = "phantomjs", port = 4567L, check = T)
rDr <- rS[['client']]
rDr$navigate(yahoo)
doc <- rDr$getPageSource()
```

and navigated to the Yahoo page. And everything is ok, but while I try to do it once again (this or other page from Yahoo) it returns very similar page, but this seems like some scripts haven't been loaded. While I renew it once or twice or trice this works again. My idea is there's some checker when you want to load the resource from the server too quickly. If so, how to handle this programically? I  haven't found any methods in documentation something like `isPageLoadedProperly()` or so. I can set some timeout but don't know how long, is it constant value and many other questions. Anyone had that issue before?

Comment: can you add a little more detail? What do you mean by "very similar page"?

Comment: I spent some time with it and understood it's just the issue you never know when the page finishes to load. Very similar page is just 90%+ loaded. I'd be nice to have some notification when it's finished to load. Setting constant timeouts works well, but it always can fail as well.